# MongoDB help needed to update array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have this documents in a collection

```
{
   _id: 1,
   name: 'xpto',
   arr: [1, 2, 3]
},
{
  _id: 2,
  name: 'xyz'
}
```

I want addToSet number 4 to arr with update {multi: 1}, but I got error "Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array.".
I know it occurs because my second document does not have arr field.

Is it possible update array with $push and/or $addtoset with update command when array is not in all documents?

I did that with find, looking for cursor.arr and creating array if not exists.

Do you know another way?

Comment: `$addToSet` will create the `arr` field for a doc where it doesn't exist, so what's probably happening is that you have a doc where `arr` exists but isn't an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just **update** array in the **first document** you can use $push operator, like following:

**db.docs.update({_id:1},{$push:{arr:4}});**

If you need **update both documents** you can use also $push, but with empty value in the first parameter:

**db.docs.update({}, {$push:{arr:4}});**

The result will be:
*{"_id":1, "arr":[1,2,3,4], "name":"xpto"}
{"_id":2, "arr":[4], "name":"xyz"}*

Comment: To update both documents, I can't use push. When I execute this command
{"_id":1, "arr":[1,2,3,4], "name":"xpto"} {"_id":2, "arr":[4], "name":"xyz"}, {multi: 1}

"I got Cannot apply $push modifier to non-array." 
Same problem of $addToSet, if you don't use multi:1 MongoDb update only the first document.